# Ionic React my component is not rendering on first viewing using map()

Tags: database, ionic-framework, components, react-hooks, render

Okay, I am doing an application with Ionic and React. I have a problem when I'm trying to render a list of components with the map function. The problem is that the first time you visit the page nothing from my `<Request>` component is rendered. But if you interact with the page/app, for example, click on a segment button or click on the tab to enter the page again, the information is displayed. This is my code below:

```
  const Help: React.FC = () => {

    const [info, setInfo] = useState([]);


    useEffect(() => {
        setInfo(getYourRequest())

    }, []);


    return (
        <IonContent>
            <IonGrid>
                <IonToolbar>
                    <IonRow>
                        <IonSegment onIonChange={e => console.log('Segment selected', e.detail.value)}>
                            <IonSegmentButton  value="activehelps" >
                                <IonLabel>Active helps</IonLabel>
                            </IonSegmentButton>
                            <IonSegmentButton  value="inactivehelps" >
                                <IonLabel>Inactive helps</IonLabel>
                            </IonSegmentButton>
                        </IonSegment>
                    </IonRow>
                    <IonRow>
                        <p>{mode}</p>
                    </IonRow>
                </IonToolbar>
                <IonList>

                    {info.map((item: any, index: number) => (
                        <Request key={index} item={item}/>
                    ))}

                </IonList>
            </IonGrid>
        </IonContent>
    );
}
```

I fetch the data from a database from this function:

```
  export function getYourRequest() {

  let userRef: any = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  let reqArr: any = []
  let requestRef = db.collection("something").where("something", "==", "something")
  requestRef.get().then(snapshot => {
    snapshot.forEach(req => {

      reqArr.push({ "an object" })
    });

  })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error getting documents', err);
      });

  return reqArr
}
```

I have used similar methods on other pages with success, but here when I use the `map()` function I get this small bug. I have tried to make my `getYourRequest()` async and fetch it in `useEffect` with `.then()`. Or just remove the `<Request>` component and put all the code in the same file, but I get the same problem. 
Any help would be appreciated!